# How to add values to HashMap in every iteration of for loop in android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a for loop and I am adding values to HashMap inside for loop. Basically I have a post and it has comments. One post has 8 comments, I need my content of HashMap to look as shown below:

```
PostId1, comment1
PostId1, comment2
PostId1, comment3
PostId1, comment4
PostId1, comment5
PostId1, comment6
PostId1, comment7
PostId1, comment8
```

But, now my hashmap contains only the first value. Only in the first iteration value gets added to HashMap, How can I add value to hashmap in all 8 iterations.

PS: PostID should be same for all eight values.

My Current Code:

```
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < conversationArray.length(); i2++) {
    JSONObject conversationArray1 = conversationArray.getJSONObject(i2);
    contentConversation = conversationArray1.getString("content");
    commenterId = conversationArray1.getString("commenterId");
    commenterName = conversationArray1.getString("commenterName");
    commenterPhotos = conversationArray1.getString("commenterPhotos");
    postIdForComments = conversationArray1.getString("postId");
    lastDateUpdatedConversation = conversationArray1.getString("lastDateUpdated");
    dateCreatedConversation = conversationArray1.getString("dateCreated");
    commentDescription.add(contentConversation);
    commentUserName.add(commenterName);
    commentProfileImageLink.add(commenterPhotos);

    commentProfileImageHashMap.put(postIdForComments, commenterPhotos);
    commentDescriptionHashMap.put(postIdForComments, contentConversation);
    commentUserNameHashMap.put(postIdForComments, commenterName);
}
```

Please let me know what changes should I make in my code, to achieve my objective. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You seem to be unclear about how HashMaps work -- the first item of the entry pair, the key, **must** be unique, else you shouldn't be using a HashMap. Likely what you want to use is a `Map<String, List<String>>` that is implemented as a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok. i will try to implement that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Map<String, List<String>>` *to store a list of comments per post* :

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfPosts = new HashMap<>();

List<String> post1Comments = new ArrayList<>();

// Collect comments of a certain post
post1Comments.add("comment1");
post1Comments.add("comment2");
...

// Attach comments to post
mapOfPosts.put("post1", post1Comments);

// Repeat this for all posts
```

Comment: Slipped in before I could close as a duplicate. There are so many similar answers to similar questions, did we really need one more? e.g., [this Google search of this site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hashmap+string+key+arraylist+value+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) returned almost 24,000 hits, and now the site has 24,001.